# c# breaking when sql view doesn't exist

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, view

I have this function in C# that is supposed to pull up company specific data from a database view and display that information on screen.  The catch statements in this function will display a pop-up message on error if something fails.  If I run this code on a client server that doesn't have the AGENT_NAMES view on their database, the function displays the following error: "Unable to make a Connection at this Time".  I would instead like the function to determine if the view exists in the database, and if it doesn't, gracefully escape.  How do I do this?

EDIT: The DBMS being used is Microsoft SQL Server

```
private string getAgencyInfo()
{
    string agentNo = null;
    string agencyInfo = "";

    try
    {
        agentNo = Session["Variable_AgencyID"].ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        this.lblPopMsg.Text = "Connection timed out, Please Login";
        this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        return agencyInfo;
    }

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ARConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            clearLabels();
            this.txtZipCode.Visible = false;
            this.lblZipCode.Visible = false;
            this.lblPopMsg.Text = "Unable to make a Connection at this Time";
            this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
            this.txtPolicyNo.Focus();
            return agencyInfo;
        }

        try
        {
            string agentData = "SELECT AGENT_NAMES.NAME FROM AGENT_NAMES WHERE AGENT_NAMES.AGENT_NO = @agentNo";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(agentData, cn);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("agentNo", agentNo));
            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            dataTable.Load(dataReader);
            if (dataTable.Rows.Count != 0)
                agencyInfo = dataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() + " &#8212; Agent #" + agentNo;

            return agencyInfo;
        }
        catch
        {
            clearLabels();
            this.txtZipCode.Visible = false;
            this.lblZipCode.Visible = false;
            this.lblPopMsg.Text = "Unable to make a Connection at this Time";
            this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
            this.txtPolicyNo.Focus();
            return agencyInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You get permission to query the system tables of the database in question, then you write a query that looks for that view.  The details depend on the RDBMS, something you failed to specify.  Or, you can muck about with the exception object you get back from .net and see if it has any useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make an additional query to see if the view exists and then handle that condition explicitly.

Here is the query to see if your view exists:

```
select * from sys.views where name = 'AGENT_NAMES'
```

i wouldn't do this every time you query agent names or you'll be making twice the number of database calls.  just do it once when your application loads.

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the SqlException and then check for the specific error number:

```
    catch (SqlException exSQL)
    {
        // want to check for number 10034 table or view doesn't exist
        if (exSQL.Number == 10034)
        {
          this.lblPopMsg.Text = "view or table doesn't exist.";
        }
   }
```

To see what all the numbers are you can run the SQL query on the master database:

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysmessages
```

Comment: Using exception-handling for non-exceptional work-flow is not recommended.  I'm not saying this response is in correct.  It depends if the missing-view is normally expected to be there or not.  Nutshell: "Exceptions should be exceptional"

Answer (score 0):

Your can run a query to DB-schema to check if view exists.
Check this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx